# Using HP Fortify on .cs files in static code analysis

Tags: c#, fortify

Hi I have been trying to use Fortify Scanning Wizard to scan a c# repository which is not built and I am not able to build it. It seems like Fortify is not picking up the cs files / cant even locate them.

I read some posts and saying that, you can only use Fortify on C# project when
1. You can compile it and have a .pdb file; or
2. You have to use fortify plugin in the visual studio and build it.

I just want to do a simple pre-compiled static code analysis on a C# project. I did not expect Fortify cannot do that. It will be great if someone can confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SCA Documentation:

> SCA works on the Common Intermediate Language (CIL), and therefore supports all of the .NET languages that compile to CIL, including C# and VB .NET.

SCA sourceanalyzer is looking for the DLL's (and corresponding PDB files) so it does not pickup the source files for scanning.

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you have any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: So it is not doing a static code analysis? It actuall tries to build it? I cant believe they dun support pre-compiled code analysis

Answer (score 4):

With the latest version of HPE Fortify SCA 16.20 (released Dec 2016), SCA will pick up files directly.  You no longer need to either have to have the ability to compile (VS or MSBUILD) or already have the compiled .dll and .pdb files.

You can still use the old methods, but scanning the files directly is in addition.

Comment: Do you mind to explain a bit more about how to do the pre-compiled code analysis on 16.20? I updated it to 16.20 but it seems like it is still trying to build the solution.